# Android button repeat function

Tags: android, function, button

I'm trying to change textview so when I click on a button, it should exchange between 'Hello' and 'World', but all it does is change text to 'Hello.'

Shouldn't the code inside the function repeat after every button press?

Here's my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textHello;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textHello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHello);
    }
    public void funkcija(View view){
        if(textHello.getText().equals("Hello")) {textHello.setText("World");}
        if(textHello.getText().equals("World")) {textHello.setText("Hello");}
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: show your layout XML, activity_main.xml

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is this:

```
Boolean hello = true;
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text); 
Button yourbutton = new (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(hello){
            tv.setText("World");
        } else {
            tv.setText("Hello");
        }
        hello = !hello;
    }
});
```

That should be it. Any problems let me know, I may or may not need coffee depending on how this goes.

Comment: You can `hello = !hello;`

Comment: thank you for your answer, but do you mind answering why do i need onclicklistener ?
i thought i could just set a function and that on a button click it'll execute code inside?

Comment: Sure, you need `onClickListener` because otherwise there is no way to detect when the button is pressed. You can't call a function from thin air when a button is involved anyways. Just think like `OnClickListener` ties in the button to that specific java class file.

Comment: No problem, can you please accept the answer if it was satisfactory to you?